# C4715 generated in debug mode only

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

Any ideas why the code below generates `warning C4715: 'f' : not all control paths return a value` in Debug mode, but not in Release? I am building with Visual Studio 2013 update 4.

```
#include <stdexcept>

__declspec(noreturn) void raiseerr() {
  throw std::runtime_error("");
}

void raiseerr2() {
  raiseerr();
}

int f(const int x) {
  switch (x) {
  case 3:
  {
    return 54;
  }
    break;
  default:
    raiseerr2();
  }
}

int main() {
  return f(4);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The warning appears when optimisations are disabled (`/Od`). This suggests that when optimisations are enabled, `raiseerr2` is elided before the compiler checks for C4715.

The reason this causes trouble is that we usually build release mode only (since it's quicker to build), but on switching to debug our build fails (since we like to use `/WX`).

The solution is to add `__declspec(noreturn)` to `raiseerr2`. Still *feels* a little dirty though...

Comment: That seems ok to me. In C++11 you get a `[[noreturn]]` attribute in the standard for this (which VS2013 probably doesn't know about).